# Does ASP.NET Core 2.2 support external login with a Microsoft account?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, authentication

This may be a stupid question, but I am using this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2) to set up authentication with a Microsoft account for an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC web app.

When I select to view the tutorial for ASP.NET Core 2.2, it says the page is not available.

Is this because the steps are identical, there's simply no tutorial made for it yet, or does 2.2 not support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.Net Core 2.2 support external login with a Microsoft account.**

Follow the official sample document.

*Below is a screenshot of my local test.*

[image]

[image]

[image]